# Copy content in CKEditor from textarea

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I use CKEditor on a phpbb forum.

```
 <textarea id="message" rows="15" cols="76"></textarea>
```

A custom mod allows me to store quotes and add this quotes into the textarea. When I add a quote, the quote is inside of the textarea but the textarea becomes "visibility: hidden; display: none;" by CKEditor.

I need a jquery code, that sync automaticly every content from the textarea into the body of CKEditor. I know it would be easier to add the quote directly into the body of CKEditor but its to complicated for me.

with this code:

```
var writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlWriter();
CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromBBCode( '[quote]This is a new 
paragraph[/quote]' ).writeHtml( writer );
CKEDITOR.instances.message.insertHtml( writer.getHtml() );
```

its possible to add content to the body of CKEditor. Any Ideas how to sync the content from the textarea to the body of CKEditor?

Thank you

Comment: Use [setData()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are unable to handle quote content stored by a mentioned mod on your own? In that case, you may want to see [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event from jQuery. I would also avoid storing content inside `textarea` used by CKEditor. It may look like:

```
$( '.target' ).change( function() {
  var writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlWriter();
  CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment
    .fromBBCode( '[quote]This is a new paragraph[/quote]' )
    .writeHtml( writer );
  CKEDITOR.instances.message.setData( writer.getHtml() ); 
} );
```